# What are the requirements for naming python modules?

Tags: python, module, naming-conventions

I've been going through [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) as a sort of refresher. Instead of naming each example ex#.py (where # is the number of the exercise), however, I've just been calling them #.py. This worked fine until I got to [Exercise 25](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html), which requires you to import a module you just created through the interpreter. When I try this the following happens:

```
>>> import 25
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import 25
            ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried renaming the file to ex25.py and it then worked as expected (>>> import ex25). What I'm wondering is what are the naming requirements for python modules? I had a look at the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) but didn't see it mention any restrictions.

Edit: All three answers by iCodez, Pavel and BrenBarn give good resources and help answer different aspects of this question. I ended up picking iCodez's answer as the correct one simply because it was the first answer.

Comment: See also: [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/4561887)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modules that you import with the [`import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) must follow the same naming rules set for variable names (identifiers).  Specifically, they must start with either a letter<sup>1</sup> or an underscore and then be composed entirely of letters, digits<sup>2</sup>, and/or underscores.

You may also be interested in what [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), the official style-guide for Python code, has to say about module names:

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be
>   used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages
>   should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of
>   underscores is discouraged.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>  Letters are the ASCII characters `A-Z` and `a-z`.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup>  Digits are the ASCII characters `0-9`.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The explicit rules for what is allowed to be a valid identifier (variable, module name etc.) can be found here: https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

In your case, this is the relevant sentence:

> Within the ASCII range (U+0001..U+007F), the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, **except for the first character**, the digits 0 through 9.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, you can name a Python file anything you want.  However, in order to import it using the `import` statement, the filename needs to be a valid Python identifier --- something you could use as a variable name.  That means it must use only alphanumerics and underscores, and not start with a digit.  This is because the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) of the `import` statement requires the module name to be an identifier.

This is why you didn't see the problem until you got to an exercise that requires importing.  You can run a Python script with a numeric name from the command line with `python 123.py`, but you won't be able to import that module.