# aws lambda with python custom module

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to setup AWS lambda with a python script that has the below structure :

```
> lambda_function
>       |
>       |-----myappname
>                      |----src
>                              |----util
>                                              |--------helper.py
>                                              |__init__.py
>                              |---lambda_handler.py
>                              |__init__.py
```

now when deploy this code in aws lambda with zip , I am getting error

```
Runtime.ImportModuleError: unable to import module src/lambda_handler : no module name util-folder
```

lambda_handler.py

```
from util.helper import helper

def main(event,context)
    return {"statusCode":200}
```

helper.py

```
def sum(a,b)
    return a+b
```

Updated file name to show correct names that I have used in my main app.

Comment: Rename `util-folder` to `util_folder` or better just `util`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the requirements for naming python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470567/what-are-the-requirements-for-naming-python-modules)

Comment: my apologies, but in this post, I used the name only for demo purpose, in the actual app there no invalid character in the file name

Comment: @Junkrat with . Iam getting relative package error "Attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: Can you add the proper structure of your project? Including the `__init__.py` files

Comment: update structure, __init__.py files are empty